# Перенаправление стандартных потоков и в консоль, и в файл в windows

Tags: windows, cmd, потоки-данных

Не подскажите, как перенаправить stdout и stderr из cmd и в cmd, и в файл? Решение на основе powershell **НЕ ПОДХОДИТ**,  аналогов линуксового tee не подходят. 
А app > log.txt | type log.txt или app > log.txt && type log.txt не работают.

Comment: См. [tee.bat](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/unixports.php#TEE)

Comment: Как вариант, наверное, простого и короткого способа нет

Answer (score 0):

Альтернатива tee в Powershell существует `tee-object`(от версии 5.1).

```
get-process | tee-object -filepath C:\Test1\testfile2.txt
```

Эта команда получает список выполняемых на компьютере процессов и отправляет результат в файл. Поскольку второй путь не указан, результат будет выведен на консоль.

Comment: В вопросе я указал, что варианты с powershell не подходят

Comment: В любом случае ведь можно вызвать Powershell через cmd `powershell -file c:\destination.ps1` как вариант. Есть дополнительные параметры вроде `-scriptblock` чтоб не выбирать файл.